# list of values for selectInput

Tags: user-interface, input, server, shiny, output

I want to create a "selectInput" widget for which the choices of values are the names of columns in a dataset imported by a "fileInput" widget.

I tried to "tableOutput" the names of the dataset, as an argument to the "choices" parameters of the "selectInput" widget, but it doesn't work. The only choices I get in the widget are "name", "id" and "class".

Here's the code I used:

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(

  # Widget for loading data set
  fileInput("file", label = h4("Input csv data set")),

  # Widget for selecting the variable among names of columns of the data set
  selectInput("select.variable", label = h4("Select variable from data set"),
  choices = tableOutput("list.var"), selected = 1) # This approach doesn't work

  )

server <- function(input, output) {

  # The goal was to get the list of names of columns to use it as "choices"
  # in the "selectInput" widget
  output$list.var <- renderTable({

  inFile <- input$file
  if (is.null(inFile)) # To avoid error messages when the file is not yet loaded
  return(NULL)

  # After the file is loaded
  data.fr <- read.csv(inFile$datapath)
  list.var <- names(data.fr[1,]) # Get the names of the columns of the dataset

  })

  }

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Is there a way to use the names of columns of an imported dataset as choices for a "selectInput" widget?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should do the trick. I used `renderUI` to create the slider widget from your dataset

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(

        # Widget for loading data set
        fileInput("file", label = h4("Input csv data set")),
        uiOutput("myslider")
)
server <- function(input, output) {

        # The goal was to get the list of names of columns to use it as "choices"
        # in the "selectInput" widget

        output$myslider <- renderUI({
                # Widget for selecting the variable among names of columns of the data set
                selectInput("select.variable", label = h4("Select variable from data set"),
                            choices = names(mydata()), selected = 1) # This approach doesn't work 

        })

        mydata <- reactive({
                inFile <- input$file
                if (is.null(inFile)) # To avoid error messages when the file is not yet loaded
                        return(NULL)

                # After the file is loaded
                data.fr <- read.csv(inFile$datapath)
                names(data.fr[1,]) # Get the names of the columns of the dataset  
        })

        output$list.var <- renderTable({
                mydata()
        })

}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: Thank you so much, it works! Now I'll try to better understand how... :)

Comment: Please accept the answer if this is what you were looking for